# ExifTools - Add thumbnail from URL

Tags: image, image-processing, exif, exiftool

I have two images. One image is local to my machine and the other image is on a server. Is it possible to use a URL to 'store' the thumbnail for an image so it is downloaded when ever access?

I attempted to use -

```
exiftool '-ThumbnailImage<= images.mentalfloss.com/sites/default/files/styles/mf_image_16x9/public/558828-istock-865223918.jpg' dog.jpg
```

This however fails out because it cannot read/find the url (which does exist).

Can you use a URL for exiftool data?

Answer (score 0):

No, exiftool doesn't have the ability to read from an url.  The alternative would be to use something like cURL to access the image and then pipe that output to exiftool.  If you check the [Piping Examples](https://sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/exiftool_pod.html#curl--s-http:-a.domain.com-bigfile.jpg-exiftool--fast), the second to the last gives a cURL example and the last one gives an example for copying piped output into the thumbnail.  Combining the two should give you the result you're looking for.

Comment: I don't think this fits my need. I need a users computer to reach out to my server whenever the image file loads. If that makes sense.